# How to compare values of one dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

So I have a Dictionary for which each string key can take many values, and these values are divided into 2 hashsets (i.e Dictionary < string, Tuple < HashSet < string >, HashSet < string>>>)

And now I filled my dictionary as something like this

```
  Key        Values1        Values2
   A        Z B C D E        movie0 movie1 movie2 movie7
   B        A C D E          movie1 movie2 movie7
   C        A B D            movie1 movie7
  ...       .....            ....etc
```

Now what I need is to make a function that loops over values2, this function will take 2 string keys (i.e A, B) And if there was a match in the values it's going to increment a counter so in case of A and B They both appeared in movie1, movie2 and movie7 so the counter will return 3. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You need to embrace object oriented programming.  Break everything up into classes and use composition.  You are torturing the dictionary and string classes.

Comment: Well, I was going to make 2 dictionaries each of a string and a hashset but  I thought this was bad... Would this be a better start?

Comment: You will find that it is possible to do almost *anything* with your programs. You can do it, but it has tradeoffs, such as readability, maintainability or extensibility . Like @roryap, I would recommend breaking up your data structure a bit, or clarifying why you need to loop in this way to do it. It seems like your data is way too complex for a simple solution.

Comment: Well, my data structure is supposed to be a graph, and the way I filled my dictionary was to read from a file... My application is supposed to demonstrate the small world problem in 3 different functions, the first one was to calculate the degree of separation between 2 nodes (i.e A/B) and I was actually able to demonstrate it by using the BFS and making only a data structure that resembles something like this ( i.e Dictionary <string, HashSet<string>>) So the movies weren't really that important but now I need to calculate the number of movies each 2 node appeared into so I was thinking of a-

Comment: way to connect between the movies and the nodes and its neighbors so yeah that's why I thought of tuple and that's why I need to loop this way... Sorry for the rant I hope this answers your question on why do I need to loop this way.

Answer (score 3):

Your data structure looks weird. btw if you want to do this.

```
int count = dic["string1"].Item2.Intersect(dic["string2"].Item2).Count();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked but I guess I am gonna have to think of a better way to express my data structure!

Answer (score 1):

```
valueA = dict[A];
valueB = dict[B];
var matches = valueA.Item2.Intersect(valueB.Item2).Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary < string, Tuple < HashSet < string >, HashSet < string>>> dict = new Dictionary<string,Tuple<HashSet<string>,HashSet<string>>>() {
                { "A", new Tuple<HashSet<string>, HashSet<string>>( new HashSet<string>() {"Z", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, new HashSet<string>() { "movie0",  "movie1", "movie2", "movie7"})},
                { "B", new Tuple<HashSet<string>, HashSet<string>>( new HashSet<string>() {"A", "C", "D", "E"}, new HashSet<string>() { "movie1",  "movie2", "movie7"})},
                { "C", new Tuple<HashSet<string>, HashSet<string>>( new HashSet<string>() {"A", "B", "D"}, new HashSet<string>() { "movie1",  "movie7"})}
            };

            int mathces = Matches(dict["A"].Item2, dict["B"].Item2);

        }
        static int Matches(HashSet<string> hash1, HashSet<string> hash2)
        {
            return hash1.Where(x => hash2.Contains(x)).Count();
        }
    }
}
​
```